# Select Multiple Checkboxes with either Select All OR Individually

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a little situation that I am stuck with. I have an array of holidays that looks like so:

```js
export const holidays = {
  federal: [
    { name: "New Year's Day", selected: false },
    { name: 'Martin Luther King, Jr. Day', selected: false },
    { name: "George Washington's Birthday", selected: false },
    { name: 'Memorial Day', selected: false },
    { name: 'Independence Day', selected: false },
    { name: 'Labor Day', selected: false },
    { name: 'Columbus Day', selected: false },
    { name: 'Veterans Day', selected: false },
    { name: 'Thanksgiving Day', selected: false },
    { name: 'Christmas Day', selected: false }
  ],
  other: [
    { name: 'Black Friday', selected: false },
    { name: 'Christmas Eve', selected: false },
    { name: "New Year's Eve", selected: false }
  ]
};
```

My goal is to render 2 lists of holidays - one with a `Federal Holidays` label, and the other with a `Other Holidays` label. I need to be able to select all the checkboxes with an `Add all` options, and I also need to be able to select the check boxes individually.

Right now, only my `Add all` functionality is working. Here is my code:

```js
// CheckboxList component

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import camelCase from 'lodash';

import Checkbox from 'common/components/Checkbox';

class CheckList extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.array,
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  };

  ...

  get checkboxList() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    const { checked } = this.state;

    return data.map(item => (
      <Checkbox
        id={camelCase(item)}
        key={camelCase(item)}
        checked={checked}
        label={item}
      />
    ));
  }

  handleSelectAllCheckboxToggle() {
    this.setState(({ checked }) => ({ checked: !checked }));
  }

  render() {
    const { id } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={this.baseClass}>
        <Checkbox
          id={id}
          label="Add all"
          onChange={this.handleSelectAllCheckboxToggle}
        />

        {this.checkboxList}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The above is a reusable component that basically renders checkboxes with labels depending on how many items are inside the `data` prop (*array*) that is passed into the component. This reusable component is then passed into a parent component which is going to render the checkbox list:

```js
// HolidaySchedule component

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import camelCase from 'lodash/camelCase';

import { holidays } from 'modules/utilities/constants';

import CheckboxList from './CheckboxList';
import Panel from 'common/components/Panel';

class HolidaySchedule extends Component {
  get holidaysList() {
    return Object.keys(holidays).map(holiday => (
      <CheckboxList
        key={camelCase(holiday)}
        data={this.holidaysData(holiday)}
        id={`${holiday}Holidays`}
      />
    ));
  }

  holidaysData(type) {
    return holidays[type].map(holiday => holiday.name);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Panel>
        {this.holidaysList}
      </Panel>
    );
  }
}
```

This all ends up rendering a list of checkboxes with the holidays as their labels:

[image]

Sorry for the kinda long and in-depth post, I just wanted to make sure I didn't leave anything out. The functionality when clicking `Add all` for each group of checkboxes (*Federal or Other*) works fine.

However, I do not know what to do in order to also add functionality where I can select the checkboxes individually. I have only gotten as far as being able to select only one checkbox at a time, and it deselects the previous one selected. I would like to be able to `Add all` to select all checkboxes, click one of the checkboxes to uncheck it and deselect the `Add all` checkbox, and also just select one checkbox at a time. Stumped!

If anyone took the time to go through all this, thank thank you already!! If anyone has any advice or direction, then thank you a million times more!!!!

Comment: please share panel and checkbox components as well

Comment: Those components are irrelevant. The Panel component is simply a container with styles, and the Checkbox component is an <input type="checkbox" /> component with styles. They do not matter for this purpose...

Comment: i am creating staclbltz to replicate issue and just to make sure if there is any additional code in those components

Comment: I appreciate that, but trust me there isn't. There is nothing that contributes to the functionality of the above code. They are both simply reusable components to the point where you can replace Panel with `div` and Checkbox with `<input type="checkbox" />` and use `<label />` and you will get the same results... Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime

Are you looking for something like this ? I suppose this is the logic that you are looking for.

I've wrote a checkbox list demo with select all function for you. Its just logic, nothing looking fancy.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const [holidays, setHolidays] = React.useState({
    federal: [
      { name: "New Year's Day", selected: false },
      { name: "Martin Luther King, Jr. Day", selected: false },
      { name: "George Washington's Birthday", selected: false },
      { name: "Memorial Day", selected: false },
      { name: "Independence Day", selected: false },
      { name: "Labor Day", selected: false },
      { name: "Columbus Day", selected: false },
      { name: "Veterans Day", selected: false },
      { name: "Thanksgiving Day", selected: false },
      { name: "Christmas Day", selected: false }
    ],
    other: [
      { name: "Black Friday", selected: false },
      { name: "Christmas Eve", selected: false },
      { name: "New Year's Eve", selected: false }
    ]
  });

  const handleOnChange = (e, type) => {
    const { name, checked } = e.target;
    const newHoliday = [...holidays[type]];
    const index = newHoliday.findIndex(h => h.name === name);
    if (index > -1) {
      newHoliday[index] = { name, selected: checked };
    }
    setHolidays(h => ({ ...h, [type]: newHoliday }));
  };

  const handleOnSelectAll = (e, type) => {
    const { checked } = e.target;
    let newHoliday = [...holidays[type]];
    if (!checked) {
      newHoliday = newHoliday.map(opt => ({ ...opt, selected: false }));
    } else {
      newHoliday = newHoliday.map(opt => ({ ...opt, selected: true }));
    }
    setHolidays(h => ({ ...h, [type]: newHoliday }));
  };

  const renderCheckboxList = (options, type) =>
    options.map(opt => (
      <div>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name={opt.name}
            onChange={e => handleOnChange(e, type)}
            checked={opt.selected}
          />
          {opt.name}
        </label>
      </div>
    ));

  const renderSelectAllCheckbox = type => (
    <div>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={e => handleOnSelectAll(e, type)}
          checked={holidays[type].every(opt => opt.selected)}
        />
        {`Select All ${type}`}
      </label>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <section style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-around" }}>
      <div>
        <div>
          <fieldset>
            Federal Holidays
            {renderSelectAllCheckbox("federal")}
            {renderCheckboxList(holidays.federal, "federal")}
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div>
          <fieldset>
            Other Holidays
            {renderSelectAllCheckbox("other")}
            {renderCheckboxList(holidays.other, "other")}
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        State:
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(holidays, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Some tips for you, if you want the final value to be in array form, you can use `filter` and map to get the `name` of the option.

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-controlled-checkbox-list-f4t7g?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

## Update (11/14/2019)

I've recreated another sandbox demo using React class. This time, I've created a component similar to yours (CheckboxList) that has `name` and `onChange` callback. Using these props allow you to update your parent `holidays` state.

You can find the working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-class-controlled-checkbox-list-ejlfn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I think what you are missing is the `onChange` callback to update your parent state everytime there are changes made to the checkboxes. Your code are missing some important stuffs.

Comment: Really awesome solution! I unfortunately cannot use it, because we are not using hooks in our application, and each component is defined with getters and class & lifecycle methods. Not using function components or the format/syntax that you've used here. Cool solution tho, will try to reverse engineer it to make it it fit within my code guidelines. Thanks!

Comment: You can use Component class to achieve the same thing ( `componentDidMount`, `constructor` )  :). You will have to store your holidays into a state, and trigger update on your state during your checkbox's `onChange` callback. If I have the time I can write another example using class only. From what I see in your codes, I don't see any `onChange` callback registered on your `checkbox`es component.

Comment: Wow!! Awesome job man! This was more tricky that I anticipated, but I appreciate how you took the time to go so in depth and touch on everything. Thank you very much!!